# Probability mass function of floor of some continuous distribution

Tags: distributions

Say, we have a continuous random variable $X$ with pdf $f(x)$ and corresponding CDF $F(x)$.

We are interested to get the pdf of $Y = \lfloor X + 1/2 \rfloor$.

Is there any specific rule to obtain pdf of such random variable for more general case, e.g., $Y = \lfloor X + 1/n \rfloor$ or $Y = \lfloor X - 1/n \rfloor$.

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: It's all a variation on $\Pr(Y=y)=\Pr(y-1/2\le X\lt y+1/2)=F(y+1/2)-F(y-1/2).$ Just do the algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $Y$ is a discrete random variable because it only takes integer values $0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots$ (assuming the range of $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^1$). So what you are interested in is a pmf (probability mass function) instead of a pdf (although, it is worth mentioning that in measure-theoretic probability, the concepts of pmf and pdf coincide and are both referred as *densities* with respect to some other more fundamental measures, e.g., counting measure and Lebesgue measure).

For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, by the definition of floor function:
\begin{align}
 & P[Y = k] \\
=& P[\lfloor X + 1/2\rfloor = k] \\
=& P[ k \leq X + 1/2 < k + 1] \\
=& P[ k - 1/2 \leq X < k + 1/2] \\
=& \int_{k - 1/2}^{k + 1/2}f(x)dx \\
=& F(k + 1/2) - F(k - 1/2),
\end{align}
which is the pmf of $Y$. Note, technically speaking,  $P[ k - 1/2 \leq X < k + 1/2] = F((k + 1/2)-) - F((k - 1/2)-)$ by the definition of the conventional right-continuous CDF, the "$-$" can be dropped because $X$ is a continuous random variable (so that $F$ is continuous everywhere) by condition.

It is straightforward to generalize this calculation to $Y = \lfloor X \pm 1/n \rfloor$.

Comment: A pmf is a pdf wrt the counting measure.

Comment: @Xi'an Agree, I have been thinking whether I should point this out when wrote the answer but eventually gave it up considering this exercise probably comes from an elementary probability course where pmf and pdf are distinguished.  I will add a note in the answer to make it more rigorous.

Comment: Interestingly, OP used "pmf" in the title but "pdf" in the body, not sure if it is by accident or he actually also considers them essentially the same :)

Comment: The final steps $$P[ k - 1/2 \leq X < k + 1/2] 
= F(k + 1/2) - F(k - 1/2)$$ only work when $X$ is not a discrete variable or not a mixed continuous variable with a discrete component. The different use of inequalities in the definition of the CDF and floor function. (Yes the OP speaks about pdf, but also not very clearly, and other people comming across the question might think about it more broadly than just the pdf).

Comment: I meant `pmf` - it was a typo. Thanks for the insights

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The OP also stated $X$ is a continuous rv, so the last step should be unmbiguous.  But that is a valid point, I will add a note to clarify it too.